# Unit Testing with Firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am building an android app which uses Firebase as the back-end and an model, view, presenter architecture. However, the fact that Firebase is a cloud service complicates the automated testing in my android app. So far I have built most of the authentication system, but am unable to see how to implement unit tests for the Firebase code in my app. In terms of end to end testing I am also stuck.

Since testing is fundamental to any android app and without it application developers can't be sure what they have implemented is functioning as expected, I can't really progress any further without automated tests.

In conclusion, my question is:

> Generally, how do you implement Firebase automated testing in an android app?

**EDIT:**

As an example could someone unit test the following method?

```
public void addUser(final String name, final String birthday,
                        final String email, final String password) {
        Firebase mUsersNode = Constants.mRef.child("users");
        final Firebase mSingleUser = mUsersNode.child(name);
        mSingleUser.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

                mSingleUser.child("birthday").setValue(birthday);
                mSingleUser.child("email").setValue(email);
                mSingleUser.child("password").setValue(password);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(firebaseError != null) {
                        mSignUpPresenter.addUserFail(firebaseError);
                    } else {
                        mSignUpPresenter.addUserComplete();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I didn't really understand why do you need to integrate with Firebase to run unit tests. You can mock the authentication and the fetched dataset easily I think.

Comment: Could you give me an example. I'll add a method to the question for you to write a unit test for.

Comment: this is a great question: specifically i'm moving an app from a pure google app engine solution. The google backend (and its data store) have a "local" version specifically for unit testing. What is the equivalent for firebase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE 2020:
"So far this year (2020), this problem seems to have been solved using a (beta, at the date of this comment) Firebase emulator: Build unit tests using Fb Emulators and Unit testing security rules with the Firebase Emulator Suite, at YouTube This is done locally in the developer's computer. – carloswm85"

I found this https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-04-24-end-to-end-testing-firebase-server.html but the article is over a year old. I only scanned it, I'll give it a more thorough read in a bit.

Either way, we really need the equivalent of the local Google AppEngine Backend that you can run in Intellij (Android Studio). Testing cannot be an afterthought in 2016. Really hoping one of the awesome Firebase devs notices this thread and comments. Testing should be part of their official guides.

Comment: So far this year (2020), this problem seems to have been solved using a (beta, at the date of this comment) Firebase emulator: [Build unit tests using Fb Emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests) and [Unit testing security rules with the Firebase Emulator Suite, at YouTube](https://youtu.be/VDulvfBpzZE) This is done locally in the developer's computer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution - hope this helps:

[**Update**]
I've removed my prev. sample in favor of this one. It's simpler and shows the main essence

```
    public class TestFirebase extends AndroidTestCase {
        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFirebase.class);

        private CountDownLatch authSignal = null;
        private FirebaseAuth auth;

        @Override
        public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
            authSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(mContext); //initializeFireBase(context);

            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            if(auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("urbi@orbi.it", "12345678").addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                final AuthResult result = task.getResult();
                                final FirebaseUser user = result.getUser();
                                authSignal.countDown();
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                authSignal.countDown();
            }
            authSignal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        @Override
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            super.tearDown();
            if(auth != null) {
                auth.signOut();
                auth = null;
            }
        }

        @Test
        public void testWrite() throws InterruptedException {
            final CountDownLatch writeSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

            myRef.setValue("Do you have data? You'll love Firebase. - 3")
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<Void> task) {
                            writeSignal.countDown();
                        }
                    });

            writeSignal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but this will write to your production instance, no? which instnace are you going to connect to? bad, bad idea to unit test against a live prod instance even if you use a fake user to sign in..... we need a "local" firebase server for this just the way google app engine provides a local version for unit testing

Comment: @Creos You should not connect your dev code to a live prod instance in the first place; you should create a separate app with appID suffix (like .debug). This way you can connect safely to it without ruining your prod database.

Comment: thanks for your commend @AbdalrahmanShatou but that makes no sense. just "labeling" my dev code as an app with a different id makes it no safer to connect to a live prod db.  the proper way is to create a replica of prod (potentially scoping the data).  apologies if i misunderstood you

Comment: Actually, the Firebase team who recommended that, not me :) Checkout the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/ quoting: "One common use case is to support separate Firebase projects for your development and production environments"

Comment: In what module is that test? Is that test inside module app?